# issue with phpmyadmin and 500 errors

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am getting 500 errors right after logging in with my username and password on phpmyadmin. I am trying to extract where the error log is. How do I find out where the error log is written to?

Comment: What web server are you using? If apache, look at /var/log/httpd/error_log and /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate and analyse the server logs which should give further information about the error

Answer (score 0):

This isn't entirely what your looking for, but phpmyadmin has its fits. Try closing your browser effectively killing your session and get back into it. Or if you are running a local setup, turn it off and back on. I've had this happen so many times because of a conflict with the 30 minute log out screwing up.

Answer (score 0):

I got 500 errors from phpMyAdmin after updating PHP, and found the problem was that the following line in `php.ini` had been commented out:

```
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

After uncommenting this line (by removing the `;`) and restarting Apache, phpMyAdmin was happy again.

Answer (score 0):

In many, perhaps even most cases an error 500 never leaves any trace in the logfiles.

If you use phpmyadmin in a subdirectory the possibility is given that a file `.htaccess` is in a directory up from phpmyadmin. Try to deactivate the file i.e. by renaming it to `_.htaccess` and try again if phpmyadmin is working then.
I just had a case like that, I described it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58054128/1019850).